Question about electrons in tight binding model?
I was wondering, in the 1D tight-binding derivation, is the expansion of the ket:
$$|\Psi\rangle=\sum_n\phi_n|n\rangle,$$
a superposition of all the electrons or only one thus $|n\rangle$ only represent the orbitals the considered electron can occupy? If so, how come the Pauli exclusion principle be satisfied if all the electrons are in a superposition of all the same states at the same time?
And also, if it is only for one electron, how come our derivation be realistic?

The model is for one electron at a time. You get the many electron states by constructing the Fock space and filling  the energy states respecting the exclsuion principle

@mikestone Okay, got it, thank you

In conclusion, in the tight-binding model we consider only one electron per atom. We do the assumption that there is ample room in each atom's orbitals, allowing us to postulate that the Pauli exclusion principle will be satisfied. However, there are instances where this assumption may not hold true, requiring the use of alternative models such as the Hubbard model.
